# What exactly do you unlock when you sign in to your Social Club account?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

Once you sign into your Social Club account in-game, a notification pops up saying you unlocked an [Annis Elegy RH8 vehicle](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Annis_Elegy_RH8), which is awesome.

But what else gets unlocked when you sign into your Social Club account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading and referring to the [Grand Theft Auto 5 Manual](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/51371/the-free-gtav-ifruit-and-game-manual-companion-apps.html), you unlock the following by signing into your Social Club account in-game:

- Career Stat Tracking and Checklist *(makes getting 100% completion much easier)*
- Exclusive haircuts for each character
- Assault SMG
- Annis Elegy RH8 vehicle
- Free garage for each character